# Why does `renv` symlink to older package version?

Tags: r, package

I am working on an R project where the package `renv` is being used to [manage project-local dependencies](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html).

When I first ran `renv::init()` the package did its thing, found the dependencies in my project and recorded them in a local project directory. As per the `renv` documentation, each of the package files in this local directory are symbolic links to the *actual* package files stored in a global `renv` package cache.

Now, in the global cache, some packages have two versions. For example there is an `rlang v0.4.6` and an `rlang v0.4.10`. However, for some reason `renv` is deciding to symlink to the older version rather than the newer version which is causing me a headache when I try to load something like the `tidyverse` (which requires `rlang v0.4.10` rather than `rlang v0.4.6`).

Does anybody know how to fix this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renv::init()` basically "forks" the state of your user library for use in a project-local library, so the most likely explanation would be that the version of `rlang` installed in your user library is 0.4.6. You could verify this, outside of `renv`, with something like:

```
find.package("rlang")
packageVersion("rlang")
```

The simplest way to fix this is to just install an updated version of `rlang` in your project; e.g.

```
install.packages("rlang")
```

Or, alternatively, if you'd like to update all packages used in your project, then you could use:

```
renv::update()
```

Ultimately, `renv` just gives your projects a project-local library, and you are free to update and install different versions of packages as appropriate for that particular project.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I have resolved this now.